# JQuery delete older rows after threshold from jsp generated datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datatable

I'm generating a table on a webpage using a JSP script that, given a list, parses the values and generates the table. My table needs to have the same number of rows for every name parameter (2 in the example), like this:

```
id name value1 value1
0  name1 12    13
1  name1 11    9
2  name2 14    2
3  name2 14    4
4  name3 12    5
5  name3 1     2
6  name4 12    1
7  name4 15    2
```

As soon as the jsp receives a new list element that contains one of the names, that table needs to delete the older occurrence of the name received and add the new line. If we receive a new name1 list, then:

```
id name value1 value1
1  name1 11    9
8  name1 21    24
2  name2 14    2
3  name2 14    4
4  name3 12    5
5  name3 1     2
6  name4 12    1
7  name4 15    2
```

If we receive a new name3 list, then:

```
id name value1 value1
1  name1 11    9
8  name1 21    24
2  name2 14    2
3  name2 14    4
5  name3 1     2
9  name3 25    19
6  name4 12    1
7  name4 15    2
```

Here's my code:

```
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>value1</th>
<th>value2</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<td>
<c:forEach items="${my_params}" var="param">
<td>${param.param}</td>
</c:forEach>
</td>
</tbody>
```

Since I'm grouping by the names, I'm using the following Datatable code:

```
var group = $('tr.group');
var totalGroups = group.length;
var maxRows = totalGroups*2;


var groupColumn = 1;
$('#myTable thead th').unbind('click');
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        { "visible": false, "targets": groupColumn }
    ],
    "order": [[ groupColumn, 'asc' ]],
    "displayLength": 40,
    "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
        var api = this.api();
        var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
        var last=null;

        api.column(groupColumn, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
            if ( last !== group ) {
                $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                    '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                );

                last = group;
            }
        } );
         if(table.rows().count() >= maxRows) {table.row(0).remove().draw()};
    }
} );
```

Using this method I'm never deleting the older row, because as soon as I'm reloading the page it gets deleted. Using the code provided as soon as I'm reloading the page the row gets redrawn again. How can I remove the older row as soon as a new one gets drawn after a certain threshold?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself with a little workaround. Basically, as soon as the table is generated, I'm calling a function that deletes the first row (oldest id) in a way that the user doesn't see anything and the threshold is overtaken.

Similar to this:

```
function deleteRow() {
    var group = //get//group//names
    var threshold = totalGroupLines
   while(myTable.rows().count() >= threshold){
     myTable.row(0).remove().draw();
}
}
```